# Documentation: suggest delete Firebase TAG

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was taking a look to the new Documentation, and I was wondering why is there a Firebase **tag** AND a Firebase **topic** inside the Android **tag**. Because now people are also writing documentation for Android inside the Firebase tag. Shouldn't we delete the Firebase tag and add a Firebase topic to each platform tag (Android, IOS, Web) ?

This is what is happening:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Do you see Firebase section in official documentation of Android or iOS? Firebase is a third-party (well, almost) cloud service which is **inherent to neither Android nor iOS**. As such, it must exist in a **separate tag** and topics about it must be moved from both Android and iOS.

Some topics in Android and iOS may link to Firebase documentation, like "you can do this and this using these services." But if we start including every single thing which can be used in Android, Android will suck half of Documentation like a black hole, including all sorts of services, databases, languages etc. "Where's C# documentaion? It's in Android, because it can be used there."

P. S. There's no such thing as a Web tag, and I hope never will.

Comment: My bad you're right. But for sure there is currently duplicated posts which have to be moved (or removed)

Comment: There is a "string" tag though... Equally useful as "web". Just trying to do my research on what does it take to get a tag deleted before asking on Meta...